# Dynamic Conversion Chart

Tags: javascript, dynamic, html-table

I need to create a conversion chart from degrees Celsius, to degrees Fahrenheit. To do this, I need to use javascript to prompt the user for input for three things: starting temp in Celsius, ending, and the interval at which it will be displayed. Example:

```
start:100
end:10
interval:10

100   conv
90    conv
80    conv
70    conv
...   conv
10    conv
```

Additionally, this data needs to be displayed in a table. Our instructor has not taught us how to dynamically change or create html or css elements, so I'm a little lost on how I will get the specific amount of cols and rows that ill need, and how I'll get the data in the right position before and after conversion.

Please help!

*EDIT* so I've been trying, and so far I have something. it looks like:

```
    <script language = "javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function prompts()
    {
        var startingTemp = prompt("Please enter the starting temperature.","Degrees Celsius");
        var endingTemp = prompt("Please enter the ending tempurature.","Degrees Celsius");
        var intervalTemp = prompt("What interval do you wish to display between the two?","Interval Number");
    }

    function table()
    {
        var myTable= "<table><tr><th>Celsius</th>";
        myTable+= "<th>Farhenheit</th></tr>";

        myTable+= "<tr><td>"+startingTemp"</td>";
        myTable+= "<td>212</td></tr>";

        myTable+= "</table>";

        document.write(myTable);
    }

    prompts();
    table();
    </script>
```

however, the line where I have "+startingTemp" somehow messes it all up and won't print anything. With this included, the table doesn't print anymore and I'm also not being prompted when I reload the page. I'm just trying to get the value of startingTemp displayed there.

Comment: I think I saw this somewhere...  If you type some keywords into Google and search I bet it will lead you to the answer.

Comment: What have you tried? We'd be more than willing to help you with your code if you get stuck but you should really take a shot at the initial idea first.

Comment: ... I don't know what to try exactly. I tried looking up different things. I tried to create a table with javascript in the first place, and it didn't really work, and wasn't dynamic in regards to user input. I can do the conversion easily, it's just getting the right amount of cols and rows and getting the data in the right positions. My professor literally hasn't talked about dynamic objects in javascript, at all.